# Explicit Siegel-Walfisz theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Siegel-Walfisz theorem estates, given a fixed N, exists a $C_N >0$ only function of $N$ such us  $\pi(x; q,a) =  \frac{Li(x)}{\phi(x)} + O(x\cdot e^{-\frac{C_N}{2}(\sqrt{\log{x}})})$ when $q \le \log^N{x} $

My question is simple, is there any reference I can use to get the values of $k$, $x_0$,  $C_N$ in the next expression:

$\pi(x; q,a) \le \frac{Li(x)}{\phi(x)} +  k\cdot x\cdot e^{-\frac{C_N}{2}(\sqrt{\log{x}})}$ when $q \le \log^N{x} $, $x > x_0$ and fixing N to any value $N < 2$ but as close as possible to 2?

Comment: According to Gerald Tenenbaum &  Michel Mendès in  "The Prime Numbers and Their Distribution",   page 59: It is possible to find such numbers using Polya-Vinogradov inequality, or based on theory of real quadratic forms.

Comment: You need an explicit zero-free region for $F(s;q,a) = \sum_{n\equiv a \bmod q} \Lambda(n) n^{-s}$ together with an explicit bound for $|F|$ to obtain a bound for $\psi(x;q,a) -\frac{x}{\phi(q)}$.